# Import Github repositories button disabled when go to import github repo in jFrog/Bintray to upload library

Tags: android, bintray, jfrog-cli

I want to upload my own library project to jCenter/Bintray so for that I have followed and all the steps from following websites

**Ref Website Link:**

- https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890
- https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-android-9a4642e5fecc

My bintrayUpload command executed successfully as below

[image]

Now when I will go for import Github Repo then it will always so this page with a disabled button as below.

[image]

I have already allowed permission for grant access on this repo in github

[image]

This is my Project level **`build.gradle`** file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0-alpha06'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**`build.gradle`** file under app directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

publish {

    def groupProjectID = 'com.nip.test'
    def artifactProjectID = 'nip-test'
    def publishVersionID = '1.0'

    userOrg = 'testing-007'
    repoName = 'MyTestRepo'
    groupId = groupProjectID
    artifactId = artifactProjectID
    publishVersion = publishVersionID
    desc = 'Android library for displaying data on basic calculation.'
    website = 'https://github.com/testing-tech/MyTestRepo'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
//        applicationId "com.nip.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-rc02"
}
```

But still, the issue occurred. What is the solution to this?

Comment: The gradle log says `Repository name, package name or version name are null for project: project ":app"`. So I suspect the upload fails, even if it claims that the build is successful.

Comment: @Benoit I have added all the info as error says the `package name` or `version name` are null , please have a look at my question it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select the checkbox beside the repository name from the image below, it will enable the option to import after your selection.

[image]

Voila!!!
Happy coding. :)